# Botpress error: No such table: web_conversations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, bots

I followed the tutorial at the official page (https://botpress.io/docs/latest/getting_started/install/) for creating a botpress bot.

When I run my project, there is an error in the logs: `"ERROR: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: web_conversations"`

I thought, botpress itself does creating this table while installing. What can I do?

I know, what this error means, but I do not know, how to solve. Where should I create this table? Which fields are required? There is nothing in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the developer from Botpress and they told me, that this is a problem with version 10.28.0. Just install version 10.27.1 with npm: `npm install -g botpress@10.27.1` and it works fine :)